# Delete numbers below a certain number in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers

Today i'm facing a really weird problem.
I'm actually trying to delete numbers below a certain number in an array.

I have this array [1, 7, 2, 3, 90, 4, 70, 20] and I only want the numbers greater than 20 !

So I should have that in output : [90, 70]

But Instead I have this array : [7, 3, 90, 70, 20] ???

Here is my code :

```js
function superior() {
  var arr = [1, 7, 2, 3, 90, 4, 70, 20]

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < 20) {
      arr.splice(arr.indexOf(arr[i]), 1);
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }

  return arr;
}

console.log(superior());
```

Comment: The effect you're seeing is due to the fact that the array length *changes* when you splice out a value. After the splice, `arr[i]` is the *next* value you *should* examine, but because at the end of the loop `i` is incremented, the value is skipped.

Comment: Your code is correct it's the else that is causing an issue. Just remove the else. When the first element less than 20 is encountered it breaks out of the for loop.

Comment: Thank's, it's crystal clear now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mutating an array while you're looping through it is always going to be tricky. If you shrink the size of the array, but don't change `i`, then you're can end up interacting with the wrong element of the array the next time through the loop. Also, using `break` will stop the loop from running entirely, and so skip the rest of the array. You may have meant to use `continue`, but since you're on the last line of the loop anyway, continue isn't needed.

Rather than trying to change the array and loop through it at the same time, i'd recommend creating a new array. Then you can loop through the old one unhindered:

```js
const arr = [1, 7, 2, 3, 90, 4, 70, 20]
const newArr = []

for (const i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] >= 20) {
    newArr.push(arr[i]);
  }
}

console.log(newArr)
```

Filtering an array like this is a very common thing to do, so there are built in tools to do it for you. Every array has a `.filter` method. You pass into it a function describing what elements you want to keep, and it will produce the new array for you:

```js
const arr = [1, 7, 2, 3, 90, 4, 70, 20]
const newArr = arr.filter(element => element >= 20);

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, it's way more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter them out according to a condition.

And replace your existing array with the filtered one. Or if you don't want to replace it, use another variable and assign the filtered value to that variable.

`var newArray = array.filter(item => item > 20)`

Check [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var array =  [1, 7, 2, 3, 90, 4, 70, 20];
array = array.filter(item => item > 20)
console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.filter()`

```js
var arr = [1, 7, 2, 3, 90, 4, 70, 20] 

var filteredArr = arr.filter(item => item > 20);

console.log(filteredArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate from the end and omit `indexOf`, because you have already the index `i`.

This appoach loops from the end and after splicing, the remaining lower indices remains.

```js
function superior() {
  var array = [1, 7, 2, 3, 90, 4, 70, 20],
      i = array.length;

  while (i--) if (array[i] < 20) array.splice(i, 1);
  return array;
}

console.log(superior());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use temporary array to push new values.

```
function superior() {
  var arr = [1, 7, 2, 3, 90, 4, 70, 20];
  temp_arr = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > 20) {
      temp_arr.push(arr[i]);
    }    
  }
  return temp_arr;
}

console.log(superior());
```